# Initiate Jenkins job on salve X while it’s running on slave Y

Tags: jenkins

Let’s say I have Jenkins job that should be running on a slave for several hours, is there a way that while job is running to run it but this time on a different slave so same job will run on 2 salves in parallel ?
Currently when I try to do that I get something like that:

```
(pending—Build # is already in progress )
```

Comment: Jenkins has a check box: "Execute concurrent builds if necessary"
If you check this, then it'll start multiple builds for a job. Also, make sure that build job is not tied to a given slave.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how did I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check "Execute concurrent builds" in the job.

You will also have to install https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin

This will allow you to specify how many runs you want your job to execute concurrently and how many runs **per slave** - so you won't have to limit the executors on your slaves to one, and that way you can always assure there will be no 2 parallel runs on one slave.

Good luck!